# Create text file with the name as System date

Tags: embedded-linux

HI
I want to create a text file with the name as SYSTEM DATE...
for example---28/04/2008:9:11:50.txt
The File name should be allocated on dynamically.....

can u provide the c code for this..

Plese Help me...

Answer (score 0):

Use strftime to calcule the name of the file:

http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strfti.html